# I want to copy Data from Excel without using Interop.Excel in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, copy

I want to copy Excel data might be single row or multiple rows but don't want to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` since server where I run the code does not have microsoft office installed. 
Copied row(s) should go to clipboard so that I can perform `ctrl+V` operation in my application.
Please suggest an efficient way of doing it.
I don't want to read it as Dataset as it won't allow me to copy the data to Clipboard

Comment: Question you are referring to is for only reading excel Which I am able to do but I am not able to Copy from the sheet so that the data goes into clipboard and can be used in my application.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I don't want to read excel here I want to copy its data to clipboard so that I can perform ctrl+V on my application to paste the data. Could you please see if you have any solution.

Comment: You. won't get a full solution on SO. The duplicate does get you data from excel. then you can search on SO for pasting in Clipboard.

Comment: Who the h marked this as duplicate? It is not!